# Continue the last VIM syntax highlight until a new keyword appears?

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting

I'm trying to write a custom syntax highlight for a log file.
Each log line starts with a well-defined header, e.g.:

```
TRACE: text text text
DEBUG: text text text
```

The TRACE and DEBUG lines will have different colors, e.g.:

```
:syn match logTrace "^\d\{4}-\d\{2}-\d\{2} \d\{2}:\d\{2}:\d\{2}|TRACE|.*"
:syn match logDebug "^\d\{4}-\d\{2}-\d\{2} \d\{2}:\d\{2}:\d\{2}|DEBUG|.*"

hi def logTrace ctermfg=darkgray
hi def logDebug ctermfg=lightgray
```

The problem is that there may be cases where a log entry will span over several lines, e.g.:

```
TRACE: Here's a list of files:
file1.ext
file2.ext
file3.ext
DEBUG: text text text
```

Thus my question is: Is there any way to tell the syntax highlighting engine to continue coloring unregocnized line (e.g. file1.ext in the above example) with the same color that was used in the last detected line (the TRACE line in the above example)?

Thank you.

---

### **EDIT:**

The above example was a simplified case. My log actually contains INFO, ERROR, EXCEPTION and FATAL log types as well, and each line starts with a time-stamp.
Log lines look something like this:

```
2013-04-11 13:36:05|TRACE|texttexttexttexttext
2013-04-11 13:36:07|INFO|texttexttexttexttexttext
another line
another line
2013-04-11 13:36:10|DEBUG|texttexttexttext
2013-04-11 13:36:10|ERROR|texttexttexttexttexttext
another line
another line
another line
2013-04-11 13:36:10|DEBUG|texttexttexttext
```

**I ended up implementing Ineo's region idea. Here's how it looks:**

```
:syn region logTrace start=+^\d\{4}-\d\{2}-\d\{2} \d\{2}:\d\{2}:\d\{2}|TRACE|+ end=+^\d\{4}-\d\{2}-\d\{2} \d\{2}:\d\{2}:\d\{2}|+me=e-22
:syn region logDebug start=+^\d\{4}-\d\{2}-\d\{2} \d\{2}:\d\{2}:\d\{2}|DEBUG|+ end=+^\d\{4}-\d\{2}-\d\{2} \d\{2}:\d\{2}:\d\{2}|+me=e-22
:syn region logInfo start=+^\d\{4}-\d\{2}-\d\{2} \d\{2}:\d\{2}:\d\{2}|INFO|+ end=+^\d\{4}-\d\{2}-\d\{2} \d\{2}:\d\{2}:\d\{2}|+me=e-22
:syn region logError start=+^\d\{4}-\d\{2}-\d\{2} \d\{2}:\d\{2}:\d\{2}|ERROR|+ end=+^\d\{4}-\d\{2}-\d\{2} \d\{2}:\d\{2}:\d\{2}|+me=e-22
:syn region logException start=+^\d\{4}-\d\{2}-\d\{2} \d\{2}:\d\{2}:\d\{2}|EXCEPTION|+ end=+^\d\{4}-\d\{2}-\d\{2} \d\{2}:\d\{2}:\d\{2}|+me=e-22
:syn region logFatal start=+^\d\{4}-\d\{2}-\d\{2} \d\{2}:\d\{2}:\d\{2}|FATAL|+ end=+^\d\{4}-\d\{2}-\d\{2} \d\{2}:\d\{2}:\d\{2}|+me=e-22
```

- Although it looks a bit messy - it works just fine (I'd rather express the date/time pattern as a variable but currently this is beyond my VIM skills).

Comment: in this filetype you only have these two hi-groups or there are more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no notion of "continue coloring until the next syntax group"; you need to include the additional lines into your syntax group.

For that, there are two possibilities:

1. Extend the `:syn match` to include additional lines that do *not* start with one of your timestamps / keywords.
2. Switch to `:syn region` and make the region end either at the next start of a log line, minus one line (use a `:help :syn-pattern-offset` for that), or at the end of the file.

Comment: the `region` is a very good tip! why I just forgot it when I post my answer!  +1

Comment: @Kent: I guess it would also perform better, but haven't checked. Kudos (and +1) for your nice answer; I love screenshot illustrations!

Answer (score 2):

If you have only two groups (`DEBUG and TRACE`), you could

```
hi def logDebug ctermfg=yellow
hi def logTrace ctermfg=green
syn match logTrace "^\zsTRACE:\_.\{-}\ze\_^DEBUG:"
syn match logDebug "^\zsDEBUG:\_.\{-}\ze\_^TRACE:"
```

note I changed the color, also the timestamp/date matching, just for showing the idea, you could add it.

If you have more groups...and all starting with the timestamps. you just check the timestamp and not the `TRACE/DEBUG/INFO/WARN/...` after `\ze`. here you can make the key in a group, and reference it ..

ok, it looks like:
[image]

Comment: +1 for the idea. It's almost working but there are problems when the number of lines is larger than one pag.
Ingo's solution did the trick so I'll have to accept his answer.
Thanks for the effort.